# error -11 OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

i'm getting error -11 on this line

```
checkerror(clBuildProgram(program, deviceidcount, deviceids.data(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr));
```

my kernel is

```
__kernel void render(double playerx,double playery,double playerz,double yaw,double pitch,double x1,double y1,double z1,double x2,double y2,double z2,double x3,double y3,double z3,__global int* texture){
    //const int i = get_global_id(0);
    //x[i] = a*x[i];
    //x[i] = cos(a);
    x1 = x1-playerx;
    y1 = y1-playery;
    z1 = z1-playerz;
    x2 = x2-playerx;
    y2 = y2-playery;
    z2 = z2-playerz;
    x3 = x3-playerx;
    y3 = y3-playery;
    z3 = z3-playerz;

    double smallyaw = yaw - M_PI_2;
    double bigpitch = pitch + M_PI_2;

    double screenx1 = cos(smallyaw)*cos(pitch)*x1 + sin(smallyaw)*cos(pitch)*y1 + sin(pitch)*z1;
    double screeny1 = cos(yaw)*cos(bigpitch)*x1 + sin(yaw)*cos(bigpitch)*y1 + sin(bigpitch)*z1;
    double screenz1 = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch)*x1 + sin(yaw)*cos(pitch)*y1 + sin(pitch)*z1;
    printf(screenx1);
    printf(screeny1);
    printf(screenz1);
}
```

i can't see anything wrong with it in the terms of syntax. and i also tried replacing all the doubles with floats.

this is stupid after looking at this for the longest time i commented out the printf lines and it worked. how am i supposed to check what these variables are equal to. can someone tell me how to properly print things?

Comment: BTW when an OpenCL program fails to build, you can get build info using `clGetProgramBuildInfo` https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html

Most build logs will usually tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("value = %#g\n", 3.012);
```

prints 3.012 to console.

Printing to console should be done in a thread-safe way so your cl thread should be same as console flushing thread.

Comment: what is value and what is %#g\n?

Comment: value its just a text. %#g is double type.

Answer (score 0):

Printing output from many cores can give unexpected results. Timings are off, prints don't come back in any particular order etc. Try to print from only one work item.

```
if i == 0{
    printf(...)
}
```

You can also put a barrier above that and loop through multiple values from work item 0 if you need to.

Comment: also the printing is just for testing and for the moment i am just running this once

Answer (score 0):

> i can't see anything wrong with it in the terms of syntax.

Well try looking harder because that's not how you use printf.

If you want to print doubles use

```
printf("%f", value);
```

If this doesn't make sense would recommend reading documentation for both generic C printf and OpenCL printf.

Also since -11 is CL_BUILD_PROGRAM _FAILURE you can use clGetProgramBuildInfo to retrieve the build log and check where the compilation went wrong.

Comment: both are correct but i can only mark one as correct, thanks